# Вопрос по C++ относительно наследования базовых классов

Tags: c++

Вырвано из контекста:
"Если базовый класс для класса D является закрытым, то имена его открытых и защищенных членов могут использоваться только объектами класса D".

Почему тогда класс D не может использовать выше перечисленные члены ?

```
class A
{
public:
void show()
{
std::cout << "message" << std::endl;
}
};

class D: private A
{

}
D d;
d.show()     // нет доступа.
```

Comment: Именно что вырвано из контекста... А если он при этом открытый базовый для класса C? объекты класса C тогда тоже могут их использовать, например, а не "только объекты D"... Или давайте контекст, или при таком ТЗ ответ - ХЗ...

Comment: @Harry, исправил.

Comment: В классе `D`, вы наследуете `private` члены класса `A`, но не как не `public`. Если вам нужен метод `show()` из класса `A`, тогда наследуйте в классе `D` `public` члены. `class D: public A`

Comment: Так вы же обращаетесь **не в** классе, а **извне** - это разные вещи! См., например http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/03/blog-post_11.html

Comment: Сам формулировка источника неверная (или неточная)

Answer (score 1):

Класс D может использовать:

```
class D : private A
{
public:
    void foo() { show(); }
};
```

Но в вашем случаи пытается использовать некая функция(   main или другая  )

Для обьектов типа  `D` в данном случаи существует только один метод `foo`, выполняющий вызов `A::show()` В этом тоже заключается  отличие закрытого наследования от открытого: **"Только  члены класса и его друзья могут использовать открытые и защищенные члены закрытого базового класса "**.  А для защищенного базового класса  их могут использовать и его наследники .

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример :

```
# include <iostream>
class A {
public:
  void show() { std::cout << "message" << std::endl; }
} ;

class D: private A {
public :
  void show(){A::show();}
} ;

void f(void){
  D d;
  d.A::show(); // error: ‘class A A::A’ is inaccessible within this context
  d.D::show(); }
```

переделываем для понимания:

```
# include <iostream>
class A {
public:
  void show() { std::cout << "message" << std::endl; }
} ;

class D {
public :
  void show(){a.A::show();}
private :
  A a ;
} ;

void f(void) {
  D d;
  d.a.A::show(); // error: ‘A D::a’ is private within this context
  d.D::show(); }
```

Чтобы использовать метод `A::show` нужен публичный доступ к объекту `a`. Функция `f` не имеет право трогать `private` элементы класса `D`.

Answer (score 0):

Более точной и всеобъемлющей была бы формилировка, что для объекта со статическим типом класса D уровень доступа к наследуемым членам непосредственного класса-предка А через его статический тип D ограничеивается уровнем наследования.

Это опишет все эффекты изменения уровней доступа вдоль ветки дерева наследования. ЧТо будет с классом E , унаследованным от D, если А  - `private`?
E не имеет к А никакого доступа вообще, как он не будет иметь доступа к `private` секции класса D, и т.д.

Если объект виртуален, или, упаси Страуступ, наследования виртуальные, мы все же можем получить доступ через динамической преобразование типа, если у предков доступ объявлен более высоким.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class C : virtual public A { 
public:
    C() { a = 999; }
    C(int v) { a = v; }
};

class B : virtual public A {  
public:
    B() {}
};

class D : private C, public B  
{
public:
    int a;

    D(): C(666), a(777) {}
    C* getC() { return dynamic_cast<C*>(this);} // есть доступ к предку!
    B* getB() { return dynamic_cast<B*>(this);}
};

class E : public D {
     //  C* getC2() { return dynamic_cast<C*>(this);} // нет доступа
};

 int main()
 {
        D d;
        //C  *c = &d;  // нет доступа к оеператору преобразования
        //dynamic_cast<D>(&d).a; // нет доступа к предку

        B* b = &d;
           b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&d);
           b = d.getB();
        C* c = d.getC();
        //std::cout << d.C::a << "\n"; // нет доступа к предку С!
        std::cout << d.B::a << "\n";   // вернет 666
        std::cout << b->a << "\n";     // вернет 666. B::a и С::a синонимы
        std::cout << d.a << "\n";      // вернет 777.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметили в комментариях, вот это: `D d; d.show();` - это *не* "использование метода `show` классом `D`".

Доступ к методу `show` проверяется не для `d`, а для той функции, внутри которой написано `d.show();`.